Error [SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart
i Get This Error When In Specific Project run build runner
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart. This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.

i found way to solve problem just delete pubspec.lock and run flutter clean and pub get
